# Writing to a WriteStream from Event Handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

I have an `EventEmitter` object that I am set up to listen to events. When the event is emitted, I want to write information to a file. I have an open `FileStream` via `fs.createWriteStream(path, { flags: 'a'});` Currently, my problem is that if I emit events super fast and often, I start to get "backed up". IE `.write` returns `false` asking me to stop writing for a moment. Since I'm doing the write in an event handler, there isn't a callback function nearby to use to indicate the end of the writing process.  What can I do either from the handling or emitting side to prevent the backup?

Ultimately, it doesn't seem to matter; all of the data does get written to the file. But I'd like to follow "the rules" as best I can.

I know I can listen for the `drain` event and start writing again after that, but how can I prevent other events from coming into the handler? I noticed that if I put like a 50ms delay before each emit, the backup doesn't seem to happen but that seems kind of like a hack. Plus what if you have a slower HDD?

Below is an example of my situation:

```
var ee = new EventEmitter();
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./file/log.txt', { flags:'a'} );

ee.on('report', function (i) {
  stream.write('new file data ' + i + ' --- '  + Date.now + '\n');
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  ee.emit('report', i)
}
```

This isn't the exact code, but this is the gist of it. The full code happens when a response is sent from a running HTTP server, but if I queue up like 1000 requests, via a for loop for example, I get into the above situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up finding a much simpler solution to this problem using a read and write stream. See the code below for an example

```
var stream = require('stream');
var fs = require('fs');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var ee = new EventEmitter();
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./file/log.txt', { flags: 'a', end: false } );
var readStream = new stream.Readable();
// This needs to be here for compatibility reasons, but is intentionally a no-op
readStream._read = function() {};

ee.on('report', function (i) {
  readStream.push(i.toString());
});

readStream.pipe(writeStream);

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  ee.emit('report', i);
}
```

This will allow the Node pipe and stream system handle the back pressure in coordination with the OS. This is the preferred approach to this problem IMO.

Comment: You should rename your variables to match your function calls.  Ex readStream is actually a writeStream since that's what you're creating, and your pushing to a readable stream, not a writeStream, and then piping from the readable stream to the writeable stream.  If you fix it, I'll remove my down vote and replace it with an up vote.

Comment: I don't think that really necessitated a downvote but there was an actual problem with the code so I fixed that.

Comment: Upvoted it.  Your naming was confusing and misleading.  Looks much better now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to handle this is to `pause()` the incoming events, which you can do if the events are coming from a stream or are otherwise pause-able somehow, but that's not always possible.

If you can't pause the incoming events somehow, then the way I usually handle this is by using the [`queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) function of the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. There are certainly plenty of other ways to do this, but using a queue is the easiest way I've found and the `async` module (which is great for lots of async operations) provides a good one.

The basic idea is to put all your `write` calls in to a queue which is configured to only process 1 task at a time. If you get `false` back from your `stream.write` call, then you `pause()` the `queue`. Once you get a `drain` event from your `stream`, you `resume()` the queue again. That way you're not writing to the `stream` while it's saturated, but you're still able to receive events and queue them up for when the `stream` is ready for them.

Doing that with your example code would look something like this:

```
var async = require('async');

var ee = new EventEmitter();
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./file/log.txt', { flags:'a'} );

// Create a queue with a concurrency of 1
var writeQueue = async.queue(function(data, callback) {
    if (!stream.write(data)) {
        // if write() returns false, it's saturated; pause the queue
        writeQueue.pause();
    }
    callback();
}, 1); // <-- concurrency argument here; it's easy to miss ;)

stream.on('drain', function() {
    // the stream isn't saturated anymore; resume the queue
    writeQueue.resume();
})

ee.on('report', function (i) {
    // instead of writing directly to the stream, push data to the writeQueue
    writeQueue.push('new file data ' + i + ' --- '  + Date.now() + '\n');
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  ee.emit('report', i)
}
```

***Note:** This isn't really that different from just letting the stream buffer things internally. You're still buffering the data, you're just doing it yourself and that gives you more control over the situation.*